# Simplifying messy Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am basically trying to solve a system of two equations in two unknowns. The two unknowns I am trying to solve for are $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2}$. The two equations are:

$$
\frac{\gamma_{1}}{\gamma_{2}}\left(\frac{K}{L}\right)^{-\left(1+\rho\right)}=\frac{\left(1+\tau_{k}\right)r}{\left(1+\tau_{l}\right)w}
$$

and

$$
\frac{\gamma_{1}}{\left(1-\gamma_{1}-\gamma_{2}\right)}\left(\frac{K}{T}\right)^{-\left(1+\rho\right)}=\frac{\left(1+\tau_{k}\right)r}{\left(1+\tau_{l}\right)p_{T}}
$$
I wish to obtain $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2}$ solely in terms of all the other variables here, the values of which can be assumed to be fixed. This is not a homework question- I am working on calibrating parameter values for a simulation exercise. Any guidance on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Just replace the complicated expressions with $c_1,c_2,c_3,$ and $c_4$. Your equations become much simpler; after solving for the $\gamma$‘s, replace the constants.

Comment: @Clayton ah yes, good one. Thanks